# GASでTrelloカードの新規作成時、メンバーを複数名追加ができない

Tags: google-apps-script

GASでGoogle SpreadシートからTrelloカードの新規作成を行っています。
Trelloの仕様でカードにメンバーを複数名割り当てることができるはずですが、GASでそれを実施しようとするとエラーとなります。
解消法をご教示いただければと思います。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Exception: https://api.trello.com のリクエストに失敗しました（エラー: 400）。サーバー応答の一部: {"message":"Invalid objectId","error":"ERROR"}（応答の全文を見るには muteHttpExceptions オプションを使用してください）（行 28、ファイル「CreateCard」）
```

**サンプルコード**

```
function createCard() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const Trello_KEY   = scriptProperties.getProperty('Trello_KEY');　//TrelloのKeyを取得
  const Trello_TOKEN = scriptProperties.getProperty('Trello_TOKEN');　//TrelloのTokenを取得

  const URL = 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/';
  
  var payload =
      {"key":Trello_KEY,
       "token":Trello_TOKEN,
       "idList" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", //リストのID
       "name" : "あああ", //カードの名前
       "idMembers": ["AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"], //メンバーを登録するためIDを配列として設定。ここの指定がまずくエラーが生じている
      };
  
  var option =
      {"method":"POST",
       "payload":payload
      };
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL,option);
  
}
```

なお、
`"idMembers": ["AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"]`
の部分を
`"idMembers": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"`
と、配列を外し1つだけにするとエラーは起きません。

[Trello APIのリファレンス](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-post) には、

> ```
> idMembers
> Array<string>
>
> Comma-separated list of member IDs to add to the card
> ```

とあるので、配列で定義すればよいと思いましたが、うまくいかないようです。

その他色々入力方法試しましたがうまくいきません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 今は動作テストができず、推測になり申し訳ありません。`Comma-separated list of member IDs to add to the card`とありますので、例えば `"idMembers": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"` これでだめなら、`"idMembers": JSON.stringify(["AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"])`などはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: > "idMembers": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"

これで行けました！ありがとうございます。解決です。

Answer (score 1):

エラーに "Comma-separated list of member IDs to add to the card" と出ているので、
例えば以下のようにカンマ区切りしてみてください。

```
"idMembers": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
```

---

*この投稿は [@Tanaike さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19460/tanaike) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*